# Why is my public static array not defined?

Tags: php, object

I have a simple class:

```
class Test
{
    public static $myArray = array('a', 'b');
}

$test = new Test();
var_dump($test->myArray());
```

> `null`

I would expect `array('a', 'b')` as output, but I'm getting null. Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access it like so

```
<?php
class Test
{
    public static $myArray = array('a', 'b');
}

$test = new Test();
var_dump($test::$myArray);
?>
```

see here [PHP - STATIC](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

Comment: You don't even need to instantiate an object from class `Test` ;)

Answer (score 0):

The static you have made is not an function..

Also statics are called with `::` instead of `->` .. so you should do :

```
<?php
class Test
{
    public static $myArray = array('a', 'b');
}

$test = new Test();
var_dump($test::$myArray);
```

Comment: You don't even need to instantiate an object from class `Test` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why did you call array like dynamic method?
Call

```
Test::$myArray
```

Answer (score 0):

This class has **no constructor** so there is **no point** in doing a `new Test();` you can access the static class directly with the **class name**.

```
<?php

class Test{

public static $myArray = array('a', 'b');

}

var_dump(Test::$myArray);

?>
```

Comment: The class has no constructor, because it's a silly test class. The real class obviously has it's constructor.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer you should specify that next time in your question.

Answer (score -1):

You are accessing it as method(function)?

to receive its value you must call it as static variable

```
var_dump($test::myArray);
```

should work

Comment: `$test->myArray` is the way to access a public (non-static) property of an instance of a class. To access a static property of a class, you need to write `<className>::$<StaticName>`